# Please Wait dialog

Tags: java, swing

I have problem with showing a dialog in Thread.Sleep method here is my code, its not working.

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    JDialog loading = new LoadingDialog();
    loading.setVisible(true);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    loading.dispose();
  }
});
```

and

```
public class LoadingDialog extends JDialog { 
  public LoadingDialog(){ 
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
    Dimension screenSize = tk.getScreenSize(); 
    int screenHeight = screenSize.height; 
    int screenWidth = screenSize.width; 
    setBounds((screenWidth-400)/2, (screenHeight-200)/2, 350, 80);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setResizable(false); 
    setUndecorated(true); 
    JLabel lblPleaseWaitWhile = new JLabel("Please wait while starting the services."); 
    lblPleaseWaitWhile.setBounds(85, 22, 313, 14); getContentPane().add(lblPleaseWaitWhile); 
    setVisible(true); 
  } 
}
```

Help me to solve this.

Comment: What exactly does *its not working* mean?

Comment: What error or exception are you getting? I notice you're missing a semicolon after `new LoadingDialog()` but that might just be a typo.

Comment: Its not displaying the loading dialog. It waits for 6 sec and the exits.

Comment: missing a semicolon is a typo error here. Sorry for that.

Comment: if I run it with a regular `JDialog` in place of a `LoadingDialog` it works as intended. Did you override something like `setVisable()` in your `LoadingDialog`?

Comment: LoadingDialog extends JDialog and I've writen all my controls in constructor.

Comment: part of SwingWorker's Q&A is about

Answer (score 0):

With your custom Dialog, you're blocking the main thread - try this instead;

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    final JDialog loading = new LoadingDialog();
    loading.setVisible(true);
    btn.setEnabled(false);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(6000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        loading.dispose();
        btn.setEnabled(true);
      }
    }).start();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is working for me too, but if I have custom JDialog, like extending JDialog, how should I proceed.

Comment: @Pasupathi Post `LoadingDialog.java`?

Comment: public class LoadingDialog extends JDialog {

public LoadingDialog(){
 Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screenSize = tk.getScreenSize();
    int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
    int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
 setBounds((screenWidth-400)/2, (screenHeight-200)/2, 350, 80);
 getContentPane().setLayout(null);
 setResizable(false); 
 setUndecorated(true); 
 JLabel lblPleaseWaitWhile = new JLabel("Please wait while starting the services.");
 lblPleaseWaitWhile.setBounds(85, 22, 313, 14);
 getContentPane().add(lblPleaseWaitWhile);
 setVisible(true);
}

}

Comment: @Pasupathi Updated based on your LoadingDialog class.

Comment: Don't update UI components outside of the context of the EDT. This would actually be a classic case for SwingWorker

Answer (score 0):

You better use SwingWorkder int this case. This class allow you to create a thread that runs in background mode. It's suit very well with modal frames.